# Download from web to server without local machine

Tags: php, server

I am looking for a script (not necessarily PHP) that downloads a file from the web directly to the server itself. Meaning my local machine is completely out of this aside from sending the server a link.

I am new to this, so my first question is: is this even possible? Can you lead me to the set of functions I will need or even an example script?

Comment: This is very open ended, please say what you have tried so far.

Comment: `$filename = file_get_contents('http://www.example.com/filex.txt');`  but it depends on your server settings if this allowed.

Comment: Making HTTP requests and saving files are both pretty trivial things to do in any programming language.

Comment: @quentin: not sure if ENIAC had a tcp stack...

Comment: I want to save the file to the server, not to my computer! And this is where I always end up.

Comment: A server is a computer. You can write software and run it on a server.

Comment: if you can ssh into the server, then use wget ,  `wget somesite.com/file.txt `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using something like `file_put_contents`. That would allow you to download to your server itself.

```
file_put_contents("yourzip.zip", fopen("http://urltoyourdownload/thezip.zip", 'r'));
```

or even

```
file_put_contents("yourzip.zip", file_get_contents("http://urltoyourdownload/thezip.zip"));
```

If you're dealing with larger files, you'll want to use the first method that I mentioned. For most cases, the second method will work just as well.

Comment: @stuknet I'm unable to comment on other posts until I'm rep 50, but to answer your question to Tristan, they are downvoting you because lack of information (what you've tried, what you're doing, etc...)

Answer (score 1):

Any specfics about the file you are trying to download? It is definitely possible

`file_get_contents()` will lead you in the right direction for downloading files from your php script (http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php)

and `file_put_contents()` should get you in the right direction for saving the files to your server. (http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php)

That should work for most of your situations, but if you have large files, or complex connections you might have explore more elaborate solutions

Comment: Maybe you can also tell me why I am getting all  this downvotes? Was my question just hardly understandable? Thanks!